# How do I change "type of stream" Streaming software to Built-in webcam

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am Using Google API to create YouTube Live Broadcast. and its successfully created.
Its default type of stream option is "Streaming Software"

[image]

I need to change it to "Built In webcam"

I am using [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert?apix=true) to implement using PHP.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
try {



// Define service object for making API requests.
    $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Define the $liveBroadcast object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
    $liveBroadcast = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcast();

// Add 'contentDetails' object to the $liveBroadcast object.
    $liveBroadcastContentDetails = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
    $liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableClosedCaptions(true);
    $liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableContentEncryption(true);
    $liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableDvr(true);
// $liveBroadcastContentDetails->setEnableEmbed(true);
    $liveBroadcastContentDetails->setRecordFromStart(true);
    $liveBroadcastContentDetails->setStartWithSlate(true);
    $liveBroadcast->setContentDetails($liveBroadcastContentDetails);

// Add 'snippet' object to the $liveBroadcast object.
    $liveBroadcastSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastSnippet();
    $liveBroadcastSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($start_date_time);
    $liveBroadcastSnippet->setTitle($class_name);
    $liveBroadcast->setSnippet($liveBroadcastSnippet);

// Add 'status' object to the $liveBroadcast object.
    $liveBroadcastStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveBroadcastStatus();
    $liveBroadcastStatus->setPrivacyStatus('unlisted');
    $liveBroadcast->setStatus($liveBroadcastStatus);

    $response = $service->liveBroadcasts->insert('snippet,contentDetails,status', $liveBroadcast);
    return ($response->id);


} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    return;
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please acknowledge that *Built-in webcam* is a type of streaming that a user sets up only within YouTube Studio.

The YouTube Studio app enables one to follow a shorter path to create a live stream that is connected to a webcam; this way one is not required to explicitly connect his/her webcam to live streaming encoding software.

On the other hand, when it comes to programmatically create and manage YouTube live streams -- i.e. when one is using the [YouTube Live Streaming API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/) --, one's job w.r.t. creating a webcam live stream is a bit more involved. That's because several intermediary steps achieved through using the YouTube Studio have to be pursued explicitly within the app one develops using the API.

That is to say that, if you want to create a webcam YouTube live stream programmatically, you will have to follow all the API steps needed for to bring a stream and a broadcast live, plus the extra work of creating a suitable streaming process within your local computer that captures the webcam and publishes a [suitable encoded stream](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#cdn.ingestionInfo) that YouTube is able to ingest.

In this case, YouTube Studio  will indicate the type of your stream to be *Streaming software*, since, indeed, from YouTube's perspective, your stream is precisely of this kind.